# Android increase height of parent when textMultiLine wraps to new line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a fragment that shows a chat session and then below it an `EditText` and a `Button`

Right now I have the height of the `RelativeLayout` containing the `EditText` and `Button` hard coded.

**How do i have the `RelativeLayout` height only be the height of a single line `EditText` and when the user types enough text to warrant a new line of text dynamically re-size the height to be just big enough to contain the now larger `EditText`?**

For anyone that has used the Google Voice app or the stock messaging app you can see this in action when replying to a message.

I've include my current layout below.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:minHeight="60dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/send" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sendText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/sendButton"
            android:hint="Enter Message"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        </EditText>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/chatfragment"
        android:name="android.support.v4.app.ListFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the height of your nested RelativeLayout to `wrap_content`?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:minHeight="60dp" >
```

Comment: Last time I tried that it ended up taking up the entire screen for just the EditText...and now it works perfectly, lol I feel dumb, thanks.

Comment: You probably had one of the a child element's height set to `fill_parent` then. Don't worry layouts can be **very** frustrating sometimes.

Comment: @Sam Thanks a bunch. What a neat answer!